# Need a more efficent way to merge text files

Tags: vb.net

This is my code at present

```
Dim Paths() As String = Directory.GetFiles("files*.txt")
For Each Path As String In Paths
    File.AppendAllText("merged.txt", File.ReadAllText(Path), Encoding.Default)
Next
```

The problem seems that using this method, performance is poort when dealing with several large files.

Is there a more efficent way to merge text files? Maybe reading all the files into a streamreader first and then creating the output file in one operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("merge.txt"))
{
    string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles("files*.txt");
    foreach (string path in paths)
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
            sw.WriteLine("");
        }
}
```

I think that the slow operation is in File.AppendAllText that open->write->close the merge.txt file for each txt file in directory